# To draw multiple polygons on an image by user click and calculate their area

Tags: javascript

How to draw multiple polygons on an image by user click and calculate their area using JavaScript

Comment: Drawing them would be easiest if using a `canvas` element. Area of a polygon is not javascript specific: http://alienryderflex.com/polygon_area/

Comment: I am able to find the cordinates by clicking on the image but not able to save them to form a polygon.